# React offsetTop of div changing

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm trying to implement [sticky navbar to top on scrolling past it](http://demo.hongkiat.com/css-sticky-position/index2.html) in my react app component.

```
 componentDidMount(){                               
        var self = this;

        let $ribbonEl = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(self.refs.ribbon);

        setTimeout(function(){

            let ribbonElOffsetTop = $ribbonEl.offsetTop;
            let $body = document.body;

            stickyScrollHandler =  function (event) {
                console.log($body.scrollTop, ribbonElOffsetTop);
                if($body.scrollTop > ribbonElOffsetTop){
                    $ribbonEl.style.position = 'fixed';
                    $ribbonEl.style.top = 0;                                           
                }else{
                    $ribbonEl.style.position = 'absolute';                
                    $ribbonEl.style.top = 'initial';
                }
            }
            document.addEventListener('scroll', stickyScrollHandler);
        }, 1000)
     }
```

The problem is I need to wrap and attach my scroll handler inside timeout and hope that it gets the correct offsetTop within that 1 second. Because sometimes it takes time for the dynamic elements like images to load whose height is dynamic and can be decided on loading only. So I end up getting a lower offsetTop say 340px instead of the right offsetTop of 411px which produces bug in the UI.

So, what is the right way to accomplish the same? How can I detect the change in its offsetTop and get the final offsetTop to attach the scrollHandler?

[image: The portion in red bounds needs to stick]

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing now is to guess in advance when will your page load so that you can execute your logic. So you put a `timeout()` to postpone the logic at a future time of say 1s. Your problem with this approach is, like exposed in your question: what happens if your page takes longer than 1s to print?

I would say you should rely on `component lifecycle` instead of `setTimeout` in order to expose your logic.

In essence, what you are trying to achieve could be written in plain English as follow: "when my component is mounted, do my logic".
Now, you could directly follow with: "when my component gets updated, do my logic (again)".

```
componentDidMount(){
   // exec func()
}
componentDidUpdate(){
   // exec func()
}
```

This way you ensure that your logic gets refreshed whatever happens.

Finally, in order to stay `DRY`, you also want your logic/function to be put into its separate pot:

```
stickyScrollHandler(){
  // your logic here
}
```

This way, a quick code would look like:

```
stickyScrollHandler(){
     let $ribbon = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(self.refs.ribbon);
     let $body = document.body;

     console.log($body.scrollTop, $ribbon.OffsetTop);
     if($body.scrollTop > $ribbon.OffsetTop){
         $ribbon.style.position = 'fixed';
         $ribbon.style.top = 0;                                           
     } else {
         $ribbon.style.position = 'absolute';                
         $ribbon.style.top = 'initial';
     }

}
componentDidMount(){
    document.addEventListener('scroll', stickyScrollHandler);
}
componentDidUpdate(){
    this.stickyScrollHandler()
}
componentWillUNMount(){
    document.removeEventListener('scroll', stickyScrollHandler);
}
```